# Pading o relleno indeseado al crear Grilla de Botones sobre un TableLayout

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Estoy creando una Grilla de Botones sobre un TableLayout y todo perfecto pero no puedo quitar la separación entre celdas a pesar q le quite el padding y el relleno a la tabla.
[Esta es la captura de como se ve para entender mejor](https://pasteboard.co/JchDzNR.png)

Este es mi codigo

```
private void InitTablero()
{
    Button boton = new Button();
    int cont = 1;

    int[,] matriz = new int[Tabla.RowCount, Tabla.ColumnCount];

    for (int f = 0; f < Tabla.RowCount; f++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < Tabla.ColumnCount; c++)
        {
            boton = new Button();
            boton.Text = (cont).ToString();
            cont+=1;
            boton.BackColor = Color.White;
            boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);
            boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            boton.Padding = Padding.Empty;                    
            Tabla.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quitar el espacio entre los controles, debes tener en cuenta de que el Padding de un componente significa, en el caso de un boton, desde el borde del boton empujara el contenido hacia su centro o no, depende de la cantidad colocada, 0 o empty significa que acerca todo su contenido hacia los bordes. En el caso del Margin desde el borde del boton hacia su elemento contenedor, en este caso el tableLayout.

```
private void InitTablero()
{
    Button boton = new Button();
    int cont = 1;
    Tabla.Padding = Padding.Empty;

    int[,] matriz = new int[Tabla.RowCount, Tabla.ColumnCount];

    for (int f = 0; f < Tabla.RowCount; f++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < Tabla.ColumnCount; c++)
        {
            boton = new Button();
            boton.Text = (cont).ToString();
            cont+=1;
            boton.BackColor = Color.White;
            boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);
            boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            boton.Margin = Padding.Empty; // Tenes que sacarle el margen entre el boton y su contenedor.
            boton.Padding = Padding.Empty;   // No tendria sentido porque estaria queriendo empujar el texto hacia el centro o no.                 
            Tabla.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perefecto !! muchas gracias